# Trying to access resource id in object class

Tags: android, kotlin

So I was learning and developing something in kotlin and I got stuck at a situation where i wanted to load a pic from url. In java, I usually create a helper function in anonymous class and call it wherever i want.

But the problem I am facing, the IDE or kotlin is not allowing me to access the resource id

```
 object myclass {
 ....
  fun loadImage( ... )
  {
    val id = R.drawable.some_drawable 
    // here i am getting error, the usual error "Unresolved reference"
  }

}
```

Can any kotlin expert able to help with any possible solution?

Comment: Did you import `R`?

Comment: why you looking helper when you can use better libraries in kotlin ?

Comment: @Ashish Man!!! I did not ask for a code for loading image neither did I mention anywhere that I am not using any helper function.

Comment: you can directly access that drawable id in kotlin

Comment: @Ashish and how can I do that? Just asking. because thats what my problem is, I am not able to access id inside an object class unlike java

Comment: Your drawable are on the same module? or they are independent modules?, if yes, you should be able to do it,Clean and Rebuild

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved...

I had to import    R.java explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `R` in your class